# How to write a simple blockchain in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need a simple blockchain in python to be used like bitcoin cryptocurrency but also to be mined with cryptography based algorithms.

I have searched on GitHub but want to make my own.

My simple blockchain app that runs in comand line.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a list or json in python which contain hash of this block, data you want to store,time stamp,the hash of last block.
2. Create first block with a random last block hash.Now you can create block one by one with data you want to store in block(coins? contract? ...), calculate the hash of this block, to become a chain.
3. You can change your algorithm which create your hash,that will depend how to mine and you can setup some requirements of hash result to limit mining speed.Coins which send to miner can be written into data as public data.
4. A P2P network should be setup to enable more people to join in.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/blockchain_online_training/blockchain_writing_simulation_code_adding_blocks_in_chain.asp).

Comment: Of course if you search on YouTube you will find tutorials.

Comment: So what are you looking for? What is your exact question? To copy paste a tutorial here?

Comment: A very simple blockchain in python.

Comment: I will like something like these one but simpler whit less functionality. https://github.com/hclivess/Bismuth